# bundle.js not found express

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to express react & webpack. I've setup webpack but when i route to my home page chrome console shows home.bundle.js not found please help..
Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react28072017",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Usman Khan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/Components/home.js',
        about: './src/Components/about.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'

    },
    module : {
        preloaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules$/,
                loader: 'jshint-loader'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
 /*           {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: 'css?sourceMap'
                })
            },*/
            {
                test: /.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test:/\.js/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    /*plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/style.css')
    ],*/
    devtool: 'source-map',
    watch: true
}
```

server.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/htmlFiles/home.html'));
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res)  {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/htmlFiles/about.html'));
});

app.listen('8080', function()  {
    console.log('Running on Port 8080');
})
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Home2</title>
    <script src="../../dist/home.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="home"></div>


<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->


</body>
</html>
```

home.js(react Component)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Home</h1>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('home'));
```

and here is my directory structure
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixItz.png)

and when i got to chrome
and call localhost:8080/home
and look into my chrome console it gives error script not found 404
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qddpx.png)

Please help me..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would be great if you add a link to your project repo if possible.